# Why doesn't Eclipse generate javadoc for all classes

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I have a project in Eclipse Galileo, there is the Main class, plus other classes and interfaces. But if I generate javadoc, if I click in "all classes Frame" there is only the Main class Javadoc. How do I generate javadoc of the other classes?

Comment: Do you have selected all packages/classes in the `Generate Javadoc` dialog? What about the visibility of the classes, are they all public?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this same problem too until I changed my Javadoc dialog settings.  Specifically, in the first dialog window after selecting "Project"->"Generate Javadoc...", make sure there is a check mark next to your project name, not a blue square that indicates that only some of the classes are included.  If there is a blue square, click on it until it becomes a check mark.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue a few times myself. The first issues I hit were the ones previously mentioned.

A) Make sure you have all your classes highlighted. I.E. have a checkbox in the main project instead of a blue box. The blue box indicates only some components of that project are selected.

B) Check the visibility settings. By default the dialog's setting for "Create javadoc for members with visibility:" is set to public. Meaning it will only create docs for public objects. This may or may not be what you want.

After having made both of these mistakes I corrected them and tried again with the same results. Looking at the console it would generate several "Loading source for package  ..." messages and then stop. Eclipse wasn't actually trying to re-generate my javadocs.

Some how clicking through next->next until the last page of the dialog and ticking off the check box next to "Open generated index in browser" kicked it in the pants and it generated the full list.

Comment: Worked for me. The not so obvious ticking said checkbox did the trick

Comment: Still not working for me... Will do some troubleshooting. Bad UI decisions, as the "Finish" button seems to not actually finish anything.